# Null Pointer Creating Class

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create a class (Team) but I'm getting a nullpointer error
This is where it's called

```
Team[] Teams = new Team[6];  

private void AddTeamButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
        String InputTeamName = TeamNameInput.getText();

        switch(TeamCounter)
        {
            case 0:
                Teams[TeamCounter].Name = InputTeamName;
                Team_1.setText(Teams[TeamCounter].Name);
                TeamCounter++;
                break;
}
```

Team Class

```
public class Team 
{
    String Name;
    Player[] Players = new Player[5];
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually creating any instances of `Team`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: On what line is the exception?

Comment: You need to initialize each element of the array as they are `Object`s (as opposed to primitives), so their default value is `null`.

Comment: What is Player ?

Comment: Please, please, please, never name a variable with an initial capital letter.

Comment: Besides following the Java style and capitalization guidelines, the code itself is bad.  Please use getters and setters.  Code like `Teams[TeamCounter].Name = InputTeamName;` is always bad code.